# Looping over a list with strings of different lengths

Tags: python, loops

Lets say I have a list like this.

```
a = [1, 23, 456, 6789]
```

And I want to change the position of the elements in each position of the list. The output would be, every number is moved up one position until the end of the string, and it moves to the front of the string.

E.g.

```
1, 23, 32, 456, 645, 564, 6789, 9678, 8967, 7896
```

I know how to do this with a single number or of a string with a fixed length, but when the string keeps changing length I don't know what to do.

Here is what I has so far, but so far I'm getting caught op on called individual elements of a string - such as the number 4 - within in string - 564 - already within a list.

```
for i in a:
  for j in len(i):
    print a[len(i)-j]
```

*** Edit ***

Woops, posted it too early. Final version is above.

Comment: It's unclear how the input maps on the output. Please rewrite your question...

Comment: I posted it too early, so my question would not have made sense. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1, 23, 456, 6789]
for i in map(str, a):
  for j in range(len(i)):
    print(i[j:]+i[:j])
```

The built-in function `map` is documented on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

If the order of the numbers is relevant, then do:

```
import itertools
a = [1, 23, 456, 6789]
for i in map(str, a):
  for j in itertools.chain(range(1),range(len(i)-1,0,-1)):
    print(i[j:]+i[:j])
```

The function `chain` of the built-in module `itertools` is documented on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). You can also do it without `itertools.chain()`, but that's the first thing that popped into my mind.

Comment: Thanks :) the last line really explains everything!

Answer (score 2):

```
def rotationsHelper(s, n):
    return [] if n <= 0 else [s] + rotationsHelper(s[-1] + s[:-1], n-1)

def rotations(s):
    return rotationsHelper(s, len(s))

def rotateIntList(int_list):
    if int_list == []:
        return []
    return map(int, rotations(str(int_list[0]))) + rotateIntList(int_list[1:])
```

then

```
In [23]: rotateIntList(a)
Out[23]: [1, 23, 32, 456, 645, 564, 6789, 9678, 8967, 7896]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by - as you specify in your question - loop over the string `n` times, with `n` the length of the string. You however must first transform the number to an integer.

Furthermore you need to define a *rotate* operation that places the end of the string on the top, you can do this as:

```
def rotate (s) :
    n = len(s)
    return s[n-1:n]+s[0:n-1]
```

Then you simply iterate over all numbers, convert them to string, and repeat *n* time - with *n* the length of the string - a print and a rotate function.

```
for i in a:
  si = str(i)
  for j in range(0,len(si)):
    print si
    si = rotate(si)
```